# Can you publish a Java Application to the Google Play app store?

Tags: java, android, google-play, publishing

I know you can publish an Android Application to Google Play because it supports the Android OS but can you publish a Java Application to Google Play? I'm pretty sure you can't but I want to make sure. And if so, how can you make it support and Android device(For example have a game that uses arrow keys on a computer for user interaction and have the same effect on a phone where there are no arrow keys).

Comment: "I'm pretty sure but I want to make sure " ?????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long answer: You can only upload APK files. An APK file is the file format used for installing software on the Android operating system.

Short answer: NO.

Comment: Thanks that's what I thought, but I didn't know APK files where what android used.